# Reference request: proofs of the theorems in the paper "On the representation of the group GL(n, K) where K is a local field"

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, automorphic-forms

In the paper [*On the representation of the group $GL(n, K)$ where $K$ is a local field*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01077652) by Gelfand and Kazhdan, it is said that the proofs of the theorems in the paper are published in some other papers.

I tried to find these papers but not able to find them. Are there some papers (or lecture notes) which contain the proofs of the results in the paper *On the representation of the group $GL(n, K)$ where $K$ is a local field*?

Thank you very much.

Comment: they have a paper in the Janos Bolyai conference where there are detailed proofs

Comment: As Venkataramana points out, their longer article (circulating informally for several years before publication) appears in the 1971 Budapest Summer School proceedings and has been very often cited: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0404534

Comment: P.S. Though the longer paper doesn't seem to be reprinted in Springer's multi-volume edition of I.M. Gelfand's collected papers, the short 1972 note with Kazhdan is reproduced in English translation in vol. 2 (it appeared in the translation journal published by Consultants Bureau); the Russian version is freely available online.